# Is an array of length 1 the same size as a single variable of the same type?

Tags: c#, arrays

Fairly basic question, imagine

```
int a = 5;
int[] b = new int[1];
b[0] = 5;
```

Do both `a` and `b` take up the same space in memory? I assume `b` is larger than `a` as it has to store the length of itself somewhere, so I thought it would be `IntPtr.Size` larger, but I am not sure.

I am trying to write code where the length of the array is determined at runtime, and can be 1 or larger (<10). I didn't know if I should just make an array if the length is set to one, or to have a special case in the code and just use the underlying type for length == 1.

I know that `a` is a value type while `b` is a reference type.

Comment: What do you expect to gain by making that a special case? You will have more code to maintain and debug, and will have a less-than-marginal improvement of the memory used.

Comment: @Rawling how do you find those duplicates so quickly? That title is not descriptive at all

Comment: In this case I Googled `clr array size memory`. I know it's not the exact same question, but that should answer yours too :)

Comment: @Rawling Thanks for the link. I wish you could add more descriptive titles to other questions so people can find them better.

Comment: Just because another question can answer this question, does not mean both questions are equivalent (duplicates).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `a` and `b` will not occupy the same amount of memory.

The array container is an object in its own right. It will, somewhere, have to store data pertaining to the number of elements it contains. So it will have a non-zero size.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about it. Whatever you will gain with having an array of single element and a single value type is negligible.

For your question: As you already know, array is a reference type, so for 32 bit machines it will require a 4 byte reference and for 64 bit machine, it will require 8 bytes just to store reference. And then the extra memory required for each item in array.

so for

```
int a = 5; // 4 bytes

int[] array = new int[1]; //4 bytes or 8 bytes for reference (for 32 bit/64bit)
                          //4 bytes for `int` element.
```

Comment: I do have about >10 million of these arrays, so it does matter to me. If I can save 10 million `IntPtr.Size` that is worth it.

Comment: That would be a 40MB memory less used, if the objects are long lived, or irrelevant if they are short lived objects (collected on gen 0 GC pass). It would only make sense on a very limited memory device, such as a phone or something embedded.

Comment: @Moop, in that case, now you know that an array reference would require extra 4/8 bytes of memory just for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

`a` is a 32 bit int.  It will take up 32 bits.

`b` is a reference type, it will take up one word of memory.  On a 32 bit system, that it 32 bits.  On a 64 bit system that's 64 bits.

Of course the use of the array results in memory being consume outside of the space allocated for `b` itself, namely the actual array's memory that the `b` variable references, but when *only* comparing `a` and `b` as variables that's unrelated.